# Why is my style specification showing a ReSharper error?

Tags: html, resharper-6.0

I have a Razor layout MVC3 page as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<style "text/css">
</style>
</head>
```

After the word "style" and under the word text it is showing a syntax error that says: Element text is obsolete or nonstandard. Everything still works but I am just wondering why the error is showing. Not sure but I think it is coming from ReSharper. Prior to version 6 I don't recall seeing this message.

Comment: That might be because Jetbrains just recently added full CSS support to Resharper - however, is that HTML correct? In that case, you're missing an actual attribute to go before your value of "text/css".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the `type`.

```
<style type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `type`.

```
<HEAD>
 <STYLE type="text/css">
  H1 {border-width: 1; border: solid; text-align: center}
 </STYLE>
</HEAD>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2